# Unable to use sts to list backup vaults in Jakarta region

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, session, boto3, backup

I'm trying to list the backup vaults from a specific region, i.e ap-southeast-3 and I'm using the below code to assume a role in the target account. The code works perfectly for regions like Ohio, Ireland but errors out when using Jakarta. Listing the code and error below. The region Jakarta is enabled in the account and also the STS global and regional endpoint is set to 'Valid in all AWS Regions'.

CODE:

```
import boto3

session = boto3.Session()
sts_client = session.client('sts')

response = sts_client.assume_role(
   RoleArn=f"arn:aws:iam::{acc}:role/{ROLE}",
   RoleSessionName="MySession"
)
credentials = response['Credentials']
session = boto3.Session(
   aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
   aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
   aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken']
)

session._session.set_config_variable('api_versions', {'sts': 'v2'})

backup_client = session.client('backup', region_name='ap-southeast-3')
# List backup vaults
response = backup_client.list_backup_vaults()

# Extract and print the backup vault names
backup_vaults = response['BackupVaultList']

for vault in backup_vaults:
   print(f"Backup Vault Name: {vault['BackupVaultName']}")
```

ERROR:

```
Error: An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the ListBackupVaults operation: The security token included in the request is invalid
```

Comment: Why are you specifying an `api_versions` value? Does it work if you remove that line?